# Validating Multiple Groups of Radio Buttons - Javascript Only

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button

I'm trying to validate multiple groups of radio buttons at the same time. I'm having trouble not only validating them but also getting the error in the divs to show up as well. When the option is selected I want the validate and save the value so I can save the value in local storage later. (At this moment I don't want to print it I just want to validate by value and make sure something is selected)  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, here is my code:  https://jsfiddle.net/7ace6uws/

Since I was not able to post just the jsfiddle and needed to accompany code as well here is my HTML:

```
<tr>
  <td><label>Whats your favorite color:</label:>
  </td>
  <div id="color"></div>
  <td>
    <fieldset id="group1">
      <input type="radio" value="blue" name="color">Blue
      <input type="radio" value="red" name="color">Red
      <div>

      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><label>What is your favorite food:</label></td>
  <div id="food"></div>
  <td>
    <fieldset id="group2">
      <input type="radio" id="pizza" name="food">Pizza
      <input type="radio" id="cake" name="food">Cake
    </fieldset>
  </td>

</tr>

<tr>
  <td><label>Do you go to school:</label></td>
  <div id="school"></div>
  <td>
    <fieldset id="group3">
      <input type="radio" id="yes" name="school">Yes
      <input type="radio" id="no" name="school">No
    </fieldset>
  </td>
</tr>
<input type="button" value="Save" onclick="validateForm();" />
```

**Note on possible duplicate:** I know this question has been asked before. I've read the answers on similar questions but I'm still lost. For some of the answers I was having trouble understanding the Javascript since they used something called template literals. Some answers also used jQuery which I also haven't learned yet. Some answers also used formData (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) but I haven't learned this yet either so I'm trying to write the code using what I know so far which is basic javascript.

Comment: Radio buttons are not meant for that use, you might consider checkbox for multiple choice selection

Comment: I am required to use radio buttons, I've seen validation done on for them on other questions so I know it's possible but I'm having trouble validating specifically for my question. @codeanjero

Comment: Sorry i misread the question

Answer (score 0):

You may have some problems in your if , to compare two things you have to use && instead of & in your case what you are trying to do is an or (||) because you want to check if blue is checkod or if red is checked.

And just to add a trick that will make your life much easier, you don't need to write document.getElementById("myid")   once you put an id on an element it exists in your javascript code so you can just use it :

```
myid.dosomestuff();
```

textContent is à more rescent alternative to innerHTML, cause it gets rid of html tags in a text for example.
also you might want to get rid of your return statements :

```js
function validateForm(){

  if(! (blue.checked || red.checked)){
  color.textContent="Please select a color";
  console.log(blue.value);
  }
  else{
  color.textContent="";
  }

  if(! (pizza.checked || cake.checked)){
  food.textContent="Please select a food";
  console.log(pizza.value);
  }
  else{
  food.textContent="";
  }

  if(! (yes.checked || no.checked)){
  school.textContent="Please select an option if you go to school";
  console.log(yes.value);
  }
  else{
  school.textContent="";
  }


}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td><label>Whats your favorite color:</label:>
  </td>
  <div id="color"></div>
  <td>
    <fieldset id="group1">
      <input id="blue" type="radio" value="blue" name="color">Blue
      <input id="red" type="radio" value="red" name="color">Red
      <div>
 
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><label>What is your favorite food:</label></td>
  <div id="food"></div>
  <td>
    <fieldset id="group2">
      <input type="radio" id="pizza" name="food">Pizza
      <input type="radio" id="cake" name="food">Cake
    </fieldset>
  </td>
</tr>
 
<tr>
  <td><label>Do you go to school:</label></td>
  <div id="school"></div>
  <td>
    <fieldset id="group3">
      <input type="radio" id="yes" name="school">Yes
      <input type="radio" id="no" name="school">No
    </fieldset>
  </td>
</tr>
<input type="button" value="Save" onclick="validateForm();" />
```

Comment: I know you said I don't need to use document.getElementById, but if I'm used to using it. If I want to use it right after the function call would I use it like this? For example: var red = document.getElementById("red").value;? Just as I was using it before? @codeanjero

Comment: If I want to get the value of the selected option to save in local storage, how would I do that since the code is checking if either of the 2 options is checked? @codeanjero

Comment: yes you might do it like that document.getElementById("red").value
Well if you want to check the value, you would have to simply use the id.value and store it for instance if you store red.value = "no" then you would automatically know that blue.value = yes so you don't need to check wether it's one or the other

Comment: I'm a little confused. Is it possible to make sure the user selects an option AND get the value of what they selected? I'm not sure how I would do that at the same time if it is, because that is what my goal was for the question. @codeanjero

Comment: Yes it is possible, it all depends on how you want to get the values for instance you could have an array and push it inside every if condition, then return it at the end or you could directly use it in your if statement

Answer (score -1):

Wrap everything into form. 
Define it and then access form elements values like this for color:

`form.elements["color"].value`

Also added vales for food and school to access it same way. 
Is this what you wanted?

Also if this is going to be submit form, you just need to add required to one group of radio button so HTML does the validation and user will have to chose one from group. And only chosen value will be sent by submit button, you don't need JS at all for that.

Hope that helps, I have little trouble understanding what you desire.

```js
function validateForm(){
var form = document.getElementById("test");
  if(! (blue.checked || red.checked)){
  color.textContent="Please select a color";
  }
  else{
  color.textContent=(form.elements["color"].value);
  }

  if(! (pizza.checked || cake.checked)){
  food.textContent="Please select a food";
  }
  else{
  food.textContent=(form.elements["food"].value);
  }

  if(! (yes.checked || no.checked)){
  school.textContent="Please select an option if you go to school";
  }
  else{
  school.textContent=(form.elements["school"].value);
  }


}
```

```html
<form id="test">
<tr>
  <td><label>Whats your favorite color:</label:>
  </td>
  <div id="color"></div>
  <td>
    <fieldset id="group1">
      <input id="blue" type="radio" value="blue" name="color">Blue
      <input id="red" type="radio" value="red" name="color">Red
      <div>
 
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><label>What is your favorite food:</label></td>
  <div id="food"></div>
  <td>
    <fieldset id="group2">
      <input type="radio" id="pizza" name="food" value="Pizza">Pizza
      <input type="radio" id="cake" name="food" value="Cake">Cake
    </fieldset>
  </td>
</tr>
 
<tr>
  <td><label>Do you go to school:</label></td>
  <div id="school"></div>
  <td>
    <fieldset id="group3">
      <input type="radio" id="yes" name="school"value="Yes">Yes
      <input type="radio" id="no" name="school" value="No" >No
    </fieldset>
  </td>
</tr>
<input type="button" value="Save" onclick="validateForm();" />
</form>
```